# Order of loading DOM elements

Tags: javascript, dom

Very simple question.

If I have this:

```
<link id="lowtech" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/lowtech.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/engine.js"></script>
```

Inside the engine.js I have

```
document.getElementById("lowtech");
```

Will that always work? Does the browser load DOM elements in a linear fashion every time? Is there some specification about this process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will that always work?

Yes

> Does the browser load DOM elements in a linear fashion every time?

The exception is when JS adds DOM elements. Since events can fire at different times, the instructions to add those elements can be run at different times.

Answer (score -2):

if your `document.getElement` is *after* `window.load` event

Comment: I think that is obvious. After window.load everything is there. That is not what I am asking.

Comment: woa - that's a little harsh.  my point is that once the window.load event has fired then everything is loaded.  I have javascript that runs before load, so this is a big deal for me.

Comment: Sorry about that, but your answer is off topic. If you only want to express a thought or give advice, comments are for that. Otherwise you are just creating noise. Out of 3 questions I asked, you answered none directly. I appreciate that you tried to help. Don't be offended by negative votes. Try to learn from them. They are a lot of jerks around here, but some very knowledgeable people too. Please, feel yourself at home ;)

Comment: Answer on topic in that imho order of loading is immaterial after load because everything is already there.  There are some very polite people here - maybe you can learn from them. ;)

Comment: If I was interested in how the order of loading would be immaterial I would have asked that. Do not assume you know better than me what I need. Ask first.